# Why directive does not set class?

Tags: angularjs

I tried to write custom directive Angular JS that sets class to element depending of incoming parametes:

```
angular.module('hello', [])
    .directive("testCase", function(){

   return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'condition': '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           switch (scope.condition) {
              case "pending":
                element.css('color', 'yellow');
                break;
              case 'active':
                element.css('color', 'green');
                break;
              case "archived":
              case "finished":
              case "completed":
                element.css('color', 'gray');
                break;
                }

        }
        }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9h29R/71/

But directory does not set class, when I pass param "active"

Comment: its not a directory its directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing quotes. You need to pass string otherwise angular would compile `active` as a parent scope variable. Check the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9h29R/73/

```
<div ng-app="hello">
    <div test-case condition="'active'">Active</div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Slava. K cought the error. Just for fun, here is another way of setting styles, and any other attribute on an element using `attrs.$set`:

**The JS**

```
angular.module('hello', [])
  .directive("testCase", function() {

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        'condition': '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var setStyle = function() {

          switch (attrs.condition) {

            case "pending":
              return "color: yellow"
            case "active":
              return "color: green"
            case "archived":
            case "finished":
            case "completed":
              return "color: gray"
          }
        };

        attrs.$set('style', setStyle());
      }

    }
  });
```

**The Markup**

```
<div ng-app="hello">
  <div test-case condition="active">Active</div>
  <div test-case condition="pending">Pending</div>
  <div test-case condition="archived">Archived</div>
  <div test-case condition="finished">Finished</div>
</div>
```

**The Fiddler**

http://jsfiddle.net/zh9u45nn/2/